# rails nested resources: controller and forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a rails site that is has `gyms` and `reviews`. I would like users to be able to leave reviews for gyms. I have my tables set up as

```
class Gym < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
  has_many :reviews
end
```

and

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :gym
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { maximum: 1000 }
  validates :rating, presence: true
end
```

Right now the gym controller is static (can't CRUD gyms, as that's an admin thing) and just renders the pages w/ info. I am trying to add reviews, but I don't want to muddle associations. Here is my gym controller info

```
class GymsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @q = Gym.ransack(params[:q])
    @gyms = @q.result
    @other_gyms = Gym.all
    if @gyms.to_a.count < 1
      flash[:warning] = "No gym matched #{params[:q][:name_or_phone_number_or_city_or_zip_code_cont]}"
    end
  end

  def new
    @gym = Gym.find(params[:id])
    @review = @gym.review.new
  end

  def create
    @gym = Gym.find(params[:id])
    @review = @gym.reviews.build(gym_params)
    if @review.save
      flash[:success] = 'Review Saved'
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @gym = Gym.find(params[:id])
    @reviews = @gym.reviews
  end

  private
  def gym_params
  params.require(:gym).permit(:name, :description, :address, :address_2, :zip_code,
                              :phone_number, :website_url, :city, :state, :latitude, :longitude,
                              review_attributes: [:user_id, :rating, :body, :gym_id])
  end

  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = 'Please log in'
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end
end
```

my routes

```
resources :gyms, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :reviews
end
```

and the gym/show `link_to` which points to `gyms/:id/reviews`

In gyms/new I have the review form

```
<%= form_for [@gym, @review] do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :rating, 'Select your rating' %>
   <div id='ratyRating'></div><br>

   <%= f.text_area :body, size: '100x10' %>

   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>

   <%= f.submit 'Post', class: 'btn btn-gen' %>
<% end %>
```

this does not work. and from the link_to button I get it directing to `gyms/:id/reviews` which is an index page. I feel like there is a much better way to do this. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I see a bunch of things going wrong here your `correct_user` filter gets the user id from `params[:id]`. `flash[:warning] = "No gym matched #{params[:q][:name_or_phone_number_or_city_or_zip_code_cont]}"` exposes your users to an injection vulnerability since you are echoing back the params.

Comment: thanks for catching that! I had no idea. could you elaborate more?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by running `$ rake routes` from the console. That will tell you that `POST /gyms/:gym_id/reviews` will be handled by `ReviewsController` not `GymsController`.

Which is exactly as it should be since each controller should only be responsible for CRUD'ing a single resource.

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_gym!

  # GET /gyms/:gym_id/reviews
  def index 
    @reviews = @gym.reviews
  end

  # POST /gyms/:gym_id/reviews
  def create
    @review = @gym.reviews.new(review_params) do |r|
      r.user = current_user
    end
    if @review.save
      redirect_to @gym, success: 'Review created!'
    else 
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    def set_gym!
      @gym = Gym.find(params[:gym_id])
    end

    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

Some things to take notice of here - don't pass the user id via the form. It makes it way to easy to spoof. Instead get the current user from the session or a token.

Lets create a partial for the form:

```
<%= form_for [gym, review] do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :rating, 'Select your rating' %>
   <%= f.text_area :body, size: '100x10' %>
   <%= f.submit 'Post', class: 'btn btn-gen' %>
<% end %>
```

When then need a `reviews/new.html.erb` view that is rendered if the review is invalid:

```
<%= render partial: 'form', gym: @gym, review: @review %>
```

We can then also embed the form in `gyms/show.html.erb`:

```
<%= render partial: 'reviews/form', gym: @gym, review: @gym.reviews.new %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to create a `review` from the gyms controller.  That would be a nested form, which would require a `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your gym model:

```
class Gym < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
  has_many :reviews
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews
end
```

Your form needs to be reworked with `fields_for`:

```
<%= form_for @gym do |f| %>

       <%= f.fields_for :reviews do |reviews_form| %>

          <%= reviews_form.label :rating, 'Select your rating' %>
          <div id='ratyRating'></div><br>

          <%= reviews_form.text_area :body, size: '100x10' %>

          <%= reviews_form.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
       <% end %>

   <%= f.submit 'Post', class: 'btn btn-gen' %>
<% end %>
```

Your gym_params needs to look like this with `reviews_attributes`, not `review_attributes`

```
def gym_params
  params.require(:gym).permit(:name, :description, :address, :address_2, :zip_code,
                              :phone_number, :website_url, :city, :state, :latitude, :longitude,
                              reviews_attributes: [:user_id, :rating, :body, :gym_id])
end
```

Then in your `new` action, you are creating a new `Gym` instance and you are missing the plural of `review` in when you create a `@review` instance:

```
@gym = Gym.new
@review = @gym.reviews.build
```

Remember that a `gym` `has_many` **`reviews`** - so you are going to use the plural `reviews` when possible.

Not sure if i caught everything, but i would recommend checking out the Rails guide on [Nested Forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms), section 9.2 for a really good explanation.  Nested forms can be tricky, and another simpler option would be to have a separate review form that's created in the reviews controller (see @max's answer)

Comment: Note that there is a pretty big difference here - `nested_attributes` is only really useful when you need the user to be able to create several things in the same request. In this case it would be the same user creating a gym and review at the same time - which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I agree with you that it's less useful, as I did mention in my last sentence.  Oh well, doesn't hurt to learn a different way.